# Subclipse throws error when opening AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I just installed **Subclipse for Eclipse**. This is my first time using SVN, so any guidance or overview will be appreciated!

After installing Subclipse I was successfully able to open .java and other files, but a few, including the AndroidManifest.xml throw the following error when opening them:

org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Invalid Input: Must be IFileEditorInput

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is a Subclipse issue? Does the problem go away when you uninstall Subclipse again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referencing opening files directly from repository browser (as opposed to first downloading them into a project). Some editors as you have found have not been written to work with that input.

Right click on the file and select Open With. Note which editor is listed. I would guess, it's something from ADK. Then select another available editor (such as XML Editor or Text Editor). You may not get all the features of an editor dedicated for that file type, but at least you will be able to view the source.

The final step is to report the issue on the forum of the project/product responsible for the malfunctioning editor.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I don't have an Open With option in my version of Eclipse, but doing a Checkout and downloading the project did the trick.

Comment: Also, apparently I'm on Eclipse Platform 3.5.2, and Java IDE Feature 1.2.2. Will the usual Help->Check for Updates keep me updated to the latest version of Eclipse? Thanks again!

Comment: Checking for updates will only find bug fix releases (changes in the third version segment). To move to a new major version of Eclipse, you will need to download a new package. Currently, version 3.6.1 is the latest. You can download Eclipse packages from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads.

Comment: Forgot to add, that if you want to be a good stackoverflow citizen, you should remember to accept answers to questions you pose and vote on answers to others questions that you find helpful. That helps build reputation points for people who answer questions and is the way this site generates content and self-moderates.